# A sequence converging to zero but having a reciprical that does not got to $\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Does there exist a sequence such that $a_n\to0$ but $\displaystyle\frac{1}{a_n}\not\to \infty $ or $-\infty$ ? I know this is a silly question, but I can't seem to find such a sequence.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $a_n=\dfrac{(-1)^n}n$ for $n\in\Bbb Z^+$; then $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$, but $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\dfrac1{a_n}$ does not exist.

For that matter, just let $a_n=0$ for all $n$: then $\dfrac1{a_n}$ isn’t even defined for any $n$.

It is true, however, that if $\langle a_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$ is a sequence of non-zero real numbers that converges to $0$, then

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac1{a_n}\right|=\infty\;.$$